# Prime elements with the same norm in a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Does anybody know whether two prime elements with the same norm in a Euclidean domain are necessarily associated?

Any help will be very welcome.

**UPD 1:** It was shown that $2\pm i$ are both primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and are not associates.

**UPD 2:** Previous remark reveals the more accurate question: whether two primes in an algebraic number field with the same norm are either conjugates or associates?

Comment: $2\pm i$ are associates in $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: What do you mean by norm? It is not clear to me which norm do you consider on $K[x]$, for example.

Comment: @Joel92: An euclidean domain admits a norm function by definition.

Comment: I usually call it "degree function", it was only a question about definition. Thank you.

Comment: @user26857, They seem to be not associated, and also both prime, but as for algebraic integers, are they always (in case, they are both prime and with the same norm) either asoociates or conjugates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Joel92 's comment suggests this counterexample: for a field  $K$  all monic linear polynomials in $K[x]$ are prime. They all have degree 1, hence the same norm (the measure used for the "size of the remainder" in the Euclidean algorithm). No two are associates.

@user26857 's comment offers $2 \pm i$ in the Gaussian integers. Each is prime since each has norm $5$, which is prime, but they are not associates. They are conjugates. I suspect that behavior is general for number fields (which may be what the OP is thinking about).

Comment: thank you  for your examples, i'm especially interested in algebraic integers. I've tried some of them , and the situation is similair. It will be really nicely if it is all about the general law.